# DSAParameters are negative when converted from byte[] to BigInteger

Tags: c#, arrays, biginteger, dsa

I need to implement DSA without any libaries (except key generation) in C# as part of my homework.
I managed to generate the public and private key but when i try to get the parameters like G or Y and convert them into a BigInteger i sometimes get negative parameters. The parameters itself are positive in the byte array! They just turn into negative ones when i convert them into BigInteger. Here is the way i try it:

```
DSAParameters keys;          
DSACryptoServiceProvider DSAalg = new DSACryptoServiceProvider();
keys = DSAalg.ExportParameters(true);
BigInteger G = new BigInteger(keys.G);
Console.WriteLine("G is {0} \n", G);
```

Any ideas how i could solve that?

Comment: Most significant bytes above 127 are seen as negative unless preceded by a 00 byte. That might make some of your results negative. See the docs to 'ToByteArray'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268207(v=vs.110).aspx) the `BigInteger` constructor expects the array to be in little-endian order (worth bearing in mind if you expect the resulting `BigInteger` to have a particular value).

The remarks for the `BigInteger` constructor state that you can make sure any `BigInteger` created from a `byte[]` is unsigned if you append a `00` byte to the end of the array before calling the constructor. In your case this would be something like:

```
DSAParameters keys;
var DSAalg = new DSACryptoServiceProvider();
keys = DSAalg.ExportParameters(true);
byte[] bytes = keys.G;
if ((bytes[bytes.Length - 1] & 0x80) > 0)
{
    var temp = new byte[bytes.Length];
    Array.Copy(bytes, temp, bytes.Length);
    bytes = new byte[temp.Length + 1];
    Array.Copy(temp, bytes, temp.Length);
}
Console.WriteLine("G is {0} \n", new BigInteger(bytes));
```

Comment: yes that helped me alot and resolved the problem, thank you!